# Azure Deploy succeeds but the Web App doesn't get updated

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I have a GitHub repository with the app, and I created a workflow for deploying it via `azure/webapps-deploy`.

The deployment succeeds, I have logs about the success, I can see that the workflow succeeded, but my web app doesn't get updated.

I heard about file locking so I even stopped the web app slot with `Azure/powershell` `Stop-AzWebAppSlot` before the deployment and started it after. Everything works correctly, the web app stops, then the deployment happens, and it "succeeds" but I can't see my changes on the website. The deployment happens for the correct branch.

I'm just building the app in GitHub actions, but not publishing it. Maybe that is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I missed the `dotnet publish` step.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).